# Setting an image source to a path from IsolatedStorage

Tags: c#, image, xaml, windows-phone

I have helper methods for saving a file to isolated storage and retrieving the file path.

```
public static string GetFilePath(string Name, string Directory)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if (isf.DirectoryExists(Directory))
                {
                    string[] file = isf.GetFileNames(Path.Combine(Directory, Name));
                    return file.Length!=0?file[0]:null;
                }
                else
                    return null;
            }
        }

        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error retrieving a file.");
            return null;
        }
    }

public static void CreateFile(string Name, string Directory, Stream File)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if (!isf.DirectoryExists(Directory))
                {
                    isf.CreateDirectory(Directory);
                }

                if (isf.FileExists(Path.Combine(Directory, Name)))
                {
                    isf.DeleteFile(Path.Combine(Directory, Name));
                }

                using (var stream = isf.CreateFile(Path.Combine(Directory, Name)))
                {
                    File.CopyTo(stream);
                    File.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error creating the file.");
        }
    }
```

My model:

```
private string _imagePath;
    public string ImagePath
    {
        get { return _imagePath; }
        set
        {
            if (_imagePath != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging();
                _imagePath = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

MainPageViewModel

```
private void LoadMainPhotos()
    {
        using (var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (isf.FileExists("MainPhotos/MainPhoto"))
            {
        Model.ImagePath = HelperClasses.IsoStoreHelper.GetFilePath("MainPhoto", "MainPhotos");
            }
        }
    }
        private void photo_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {

        HelperClasses.IsoStoreHelper.CreateFile("MainPhoto", "MainPhotos", e.ChosenPhoto);
        LoadMainPhotos();

    }
```

XAML:

```
<Image Source="Model.ImagePath" Height="300" Width="Auto"/>
```

I found a converter on stackoverflow, but I cannot figure out how to use it with my code. I'm thinking maybe I shouldn't use my method GetFilePath -- I should make a method for reading a file from isolated storage and passing it to the converter?

I'm sorry, I'm still learning C# and jumped into MVVM and still am not great with isolated storage and converters and whatnot.

Thanks anyone for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way would be to load the binary content and assign it to a [`BitmapImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) entity (bound or not) and then push it as the source:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()) 
               { 
                   using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = isf.OpenFile(strImageName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) 
                   { 
                       data = new byte[isfs.Length]; 
                       isfs.Read(data, 0, data.Length); 
                       isfs.Close(); 
                   } 
               }
```

Full sample also available [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/CSWP8ImageFromIsolatedStora-8dcf8411).